# Primefaces Autocomplete from huge database not acting fast

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces autocomplete component with pojos and which is filled from a database table with huge number of rows.
When I select value from database which contains millions of entries (`SELECT synonym FROM synonyms WHERE synonym like '%:query%'`) it takes a very long time to find the word on autocomplete because of huge database entries on my table and it will be bigger in future.
Is there any suggestions on making autocomplete acting fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went to using an index solar for doing fast requests while my table will contains more than 4 million entries which must be parsed fastly and without consuming a lot of memory.
Here's I my solution maybe someone will have same problem as me.

```
public List<Synonym> completeSynonym(String query) {

    List<Synonym> filteredSynonyms = new ArrayList<Synonym>();
    // ResultSet result;
    // SolrQuery solrQ=new SolrQuery();
    String sUrl = "http://......solr/synonym_core";

    SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(sUrl);
    ModifiableSolrParams parameters = new ModifiableSolrParams();
    parameters.set("q", "*:*"); // query everything
    parameters.set("fl", "id,synonym");// send back just the id
                                                //and synonym values
    parameters.set("wt", "json");// this in json format
    parameters.set("fq", "synonym:\"" + query+"\"~0"); //my conditions

    QueryResponse response;
    try {

        if (query.length() > 1) {
            response = solr.query(parameters);

            SolrDocumentList dl = response.getResults();
            for (int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++) {
                Synonym s = new Synonym();
                s.setSynonym_id((int) dl.get(i).getFieldValue("id"));
                s.setSynonymName(dl.get(i).getFieldValue("synonym")
                        .toString());
                filteredSynonyms.add(s);
            }
        }
    } catch (SolrServerException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filteredSynonyms;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works for you, but readers should note that it doesn't make sense to return hundreds or thousands of results/synonyms from Solar's database when you need only twenty. Also, while Solar is ideal for indexing longish text documents, I doubt that it is substantially speeding-up autocomplete for your use case when compared to a plain RDBMS: an indexed table in a plain RDBMS is extremely fast, even with millions of records.

Comment: First of all, I limited the number of displayed suggestion to ten, second if you read my solr request, at the end it's returning only one result so we saved here a lot of memory.  What I'm telling here is that I set `maxResult=10` as you suggested to save memory usage and I used Solar to make fast queries for returning results. That's all

Comment: Perhaps I am reading your query wrong, but it looks like `response.getResults()` will retrieve all of the query results, so there may be many records in the SolrDocumentList. Compare this to a SQL query with a LIMIT clause of 10; it returns only 10 results. I'm glad you're getting the performance you needed, but I still strongly suspect that a few minor tweaks to your original JPQL query would have sufficed -- no need to use a dedicated search server. If someone has the same problem as you, I suggest they hold-off on installing Solr until they try some conventional SQL-query tweaks.

Comment: Ok everyone has his point of view, is that you downvoting the question everytime? You want me to accept your answer, Ok I will do it but stop downvoting

Comment: Ok thanks, one more question, I want to get the pojo class of selected value in the autocomplete, I know that I have to use a converter but I didn't get it clearly, have you an idea according to my code example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74122/discussion-between-davids-and-user2928578).

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the number of rows is a great way to speed-up autocomplete. I'm not clear on why you'd limit to 1000 rows though: you can't show 1000 entries in a dropdown; shouldn't you be limiting to maybe 10 entries?

Based on your comments below, here is an example database query that you should be able to adapt to your situation:

```
String queryString = "select distinct b.title from Books b where b.title like ':userValue'";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("userValue", userValue + "%");
query.setMaxResults(20);
List<String> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I am talking about limit on the select query not the autocomplete component, I meant that when I ran `SELECT place_id,synonym FROM synonyms LIMIT 0,1000` it runs normally but when I removed the `LIMIT 0,1000` it's not working or it takes long time to respond and a huge memory because my query returns 3 millions entries

Comment: @user2928578: But you are limiting the autocomplete component too, right? Maybe with `maxResults="10"`, for example? Why would you run a SQL query to return more results than you need?

Comment: No I am not limiting the autocomplete, I want to see all possible values, I am just putting a condition to set the minimum number of entered characters >= 2.

Comment: @user2928578: So you're running a SQL query on 3 million (and growing) entries, and you want to show the user all possible values? Even with a minimum character limit, won't that be hundreds or thousands of matches? How would that even fit on the monitor?

Comment: Supposing that I limit number of entries shown to 20 and I support minimum 3 characters for starting search, ok, the cpu is consuming 2gig of memory because of the 3 millions filled lists by POJO from the query, I'm wondering if there is a possibility to do a `Select * from whatever where name="dynamic value entered by user" ` dynamically on my gui..

Comment: @user2928578 Yes, absolutely. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I am not sure I can do that in my situation, I have updated also my question with all my code. Can you give a suggestion if you can?

Comment: @user2928578, reading your code, I can see nothing that should prevent you from using a database query similar to the one that I've provided. That said, you've put your database query in an `ApplicationScoped` bean's constructor, but with my suggestion, you would execute the database query in your ajax method, `completeSynonym`.

Comment: (`ApplicationScoped` is run only once, but the database query should be run as the user types.)

Comment: So you suggest me to remove the for loop and replace it in the while loop to add results to the filteredSynonyms list? I will test that asap

Comment: @user2928578, yes, but you'll also need to adjust your query to use the `like` keyword and a wildcard (`%`) or two.